# What the interpretation when both the non-squared and squared term are significant?

Tags: logistic, nonlinear-regression

I have a logistic regression model and added for a curvelinear effect both the non squared term and a squared term to the regression model. They are however, both significant. How do i interpret this?

Comment: Why do you find it surprising that both are significant?

Comment: I dont know, i was told that to find a curvelinear effect, only the squared term should be significant, and to find a linear effect, only the non-squared term should be significant. Now if find both to be significant, and this was not hypothesized. That's no problem, but i dont know how to interpret this.

Comment: You were told wrong. A significant squared term indicates a (specific kind) of curvilinearity, but  curvilinearity does *not* require that the non-squared term is insiginificant.

Answer (score 6):

It means you have evidence of a quadratic trend which does not have an apex at the origin.

The interpretation of the coefficient for a squared term is the quadratic slope, that's easy enough. The linear term, however, is the instantaneous slope of the quadratic curve through the origin. If the curve were completely symmetric about the origin you would see the linear term has a zero coefficient. Otherwise the slope is nonzero at that point at the apex is elsewhere.

In the figure below is an example. A response trend is generated according to the functional form on the $y$-axis label. The tangent line is plotted at the origin ($x=0$). The slope of this tangent line is $2$ which corresponds to the linear term in the quadratic formula. Least squares will estimate the same value in analyses.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm Dutch so I don't really understand what you mean. Could you maybe draw it in a graph,I hope it's not too much to ask, so it becomes more clear to me?

Comment: you can draw it yourself! Draw the function y=ax^2 for any a. If only your quadratic term is significant, then this is what you're relationship looks like. The minimum of the graph is at (0,0). Then draw the function ax^2+bx (for same a, any b)  you'll notice the graph shifts to one side of the other (the minimum value is perhaps at (1,0) now.)  If your linear and quadratic term are significant, that's what the relationship looks like!

Comment: Thank you guys so much, this makes thing much clearer. I have one more question though: does it matter if both the significant predictors are positive?

Comment: @marc just draw some plots to convince yourself. It's basic geometry at this point. The quadratic term is the concavity and the linear term is the tangent slope. There's nothing else to say.